# Published a website with web deploy to azure

Tags: azure, webdeploy

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

This error comes on a newly deployed website on azure.

http://newdemo1.azurewebsites.net/Calculator

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Why is this error for?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me when I browse to http://newdemo1.azurewebsites.net/Calculator

Where exactly are you seeing this error? Have you made changes since logging this question ?